# Use Excel/VB to create a list of product variations for food shop like size, price, plate size and side dishes options

Tags: excel, vba, woocommerce, product-variations

I´m trying to create a Woocommerce food shop with the wp all import pro plugin. 
I need to upload a list of the products with their variations.

To first do that i have a products list in excel where i´m going to put all the information. That list has variants like price, plate size, how many possible side dishes for eatch plate, and the possible variations for the side dishes.
Here´s the example:

[Products List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib70O.png)

To create the import file that lets me do all my variations at once when importing it to woocomerce i need to generate a spreedshet with the values displayed like this:

[Variations Spreedshet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU4zt.jpg)

I know that this is possible with VBA, but I dont know how to do it, and so for that I ask if anyone can help me?

[SOLVED]

Hello everyone.
Thanks for the support, bu i manage to do what I wont hith this vba code in excel, the only think taht i had to do in woo commercer was import products with the same ID, that in my case was skuparent.
I leave here the code so if anyone needs to use it just addapt it the ther need.
Thanks again.
regards
Marco

Here´s the code:

```
Sub ProductVariations()

Dim productRow As Long, variationRow As Long
Dim tamanho As String
Dim prim_acomp As String
Dim seg_acomp As String
Dim ter_acomp As String
Dim quar_acomp As String
Dim tamanhoArray() As String
Dim prim_acompArray() As String
Dim seg_acompArray() As String
Dim ter_acompArray() As String
Dim quar_acompArray() As String
Dim tamanhoElement As Variant
Dim prim_acompElement As Variant
Dim seg_acompElement As Variant
Dim ter_acompElement As Variant
Dim quar_acompElement As Variant
Dim productsSheet As Worksheet
Dim variationsSheet As Worksheet

productRow = 2
variationRow = 2

Set productsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set variationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

'loop through each row until a blank row is found
While productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 1).Value <> ""

   'get the size and color values for the current row
   tamanho = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 5)
   prim_acomp = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 7)
   seg_acomp = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 8)
   ter_acomp = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 9)
   quar_acomp = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 9)

   'make sure a size and color exists then process
   If Len(tamanho) > 0 And Len(prim_acomp) > 0 And Len(seg_acomp) > 0 And Len(ter_acomp) > 0 And Len(quar_acomp) > 0 Then



       'split the size and color into arrays
       tamanhoArray = Split(tamanho, "|")
       prim_acompArray = Split(prim_acomp, "|")
       seg_acompArray = Split(seg_acomp, "|")
       ter_acompArray = Split(ter_acomp, "|")
       quar_acompArray = Split(quar_acomp, "|")

       'loop through each size
       For Each tamanhoElement In tamanhoArray

           'loop through each color
           For Each prim_acompElement In prim_acompArray

                'loop through each seg_acomp
           For Each seg_acompElement In seg_acompArray

                    'loop through each ter_acomp
           For Each ter_acompElement In ter_acompArray

                        'loop through each quar_acomp
           For Each quar_acompElement In quar_acompArray


               'set the appropriate cells in the variations sheet (you have some more work to do here (é aqui que diz quais as colunas a mostrar)


               variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 1).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 1)
               variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 2).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 2)
               variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 3).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 3)
               variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 4).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 4)

                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 6).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 6)

                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 11).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 11)
                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 12).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 12)
                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 13).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 13)


                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 5).Value = tamanhoElement
                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 7).Value = prim_acompElement
                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 8).Value = seg_acompElement
                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 9).Value = ter_acompElement
                variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 10).Value = quar_acompElement





               'increment the variation row so the next variation goes in the next row
               variationRow = variationRow + 1

                        Next quar_acompElement

                    Next ter_acompElement

                Next seg_acompElement

           Next prim_acompElement

       Next tamanhoElement

   End If

   'very important increment the next row or only the first row will ever get processed
   productRow = productRow + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: There are several options but, to begin with an easy one, try exploring the concept of NESTED LOOPS.

Comment: @FDavidov thanks for the reply.
As I told on my post I dont really now anything about VBA, but this is a start, I will try to get this done with your suggestion.
thanks once again.

Comment: Hello everyone.
Thanks for the support, bu i manage to do what I wont hith this vba code in excel, the only think taht i had to do in woo commercer was import products with the same ID, that in my case was skuparent.
I leave here the code so if anyone needs to use it just addapt it the ther need.
Thanks again.